# Does spring java config support field injection? where field is private and has no setter method

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

How I may inject a private '@Autowire/@Inject' field in a bean while wiring by java config. If you see the example below:

```
public class HowToGetField2ByJavaConfig {

   private Field1 field1;

   @Inject
   private Field2 field2;

   @Inject
   public HowToGetField2ByJavaConfig(Field1 field1) {
     this.field1 = field1;
   }
}
```

By using an AppConfig

```
@Configuration
static class AppConfig {

  /....
  /....
  /....
  @Inject
  public HowToGetField2ByJavaConfig howToGetField2ByJavaConfig(Field1 field1) {
    HowToGetField2ByJavaConfig howToGetField2ByJavaConfig = new HowToGetField2ByJavaConfig(field1);
    //here how to inject Field2
    return howToGetField2ByJavaConfig;
  }
...
```

Comment: You can't (except by using reflection), but Spring will do it for you. If you want to do it programatically, then make that possible by adding it as an argument of the constructor.

Comment: @JBNizet doesn't my answer answer the question without reflection?

Comment: That's the solution where Spring does it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest doing this, but it can be done.

Spring `@Autowired` tries to inject beans by **Name** and by **Type**.
So if you want to create the Beans how you asked, you could do this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("nl.testing")
public class AppConfig {

  @Bean
  public Field1 field1() {
    // This will be injected inside your bean method below which creates the TooLongName bean
    return new Field1();
  }

  @Bean
  public Field2 field2() {
    // Via the `@Autowired` this will be injected in the Field of your
    // TooLongName class (this has preference because it matches the name)
    return new Field2();
  }

  @Bean
  public Field2 otherField2() {
    // This won't be used because `field2()` is prefered.
    return new Field2();
  }

  @Bean
  public TooLongName tooLongName(Field1 field1) {
    TooLongName tooLongName = new TooLongName(field1);
    return tooLongName;
  }
}
```

Comment: I just tried it, indeed spring does inject the bean field2. Although all of this is not so apparent. Thanks.